# How to get related Model id in Laravel factory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I am trying to save the image using faker in the storage folder. I want to keep the images inside the property ID folder. I have tried the below code but it is not working. It hangs the command prompt. The properties have multiple images and are a one-to-many relation. The code below is for the PropertyImageFactory class.

```
public function definition()
    {
        $property_id = $this->create(Property::class)->id;

        return [
            'name' => $this->faker->image(storage_path('app/property-images/'.$property_id), 200, 200, 'cats'),
            'sort_order' => $this->faker->numberBetween(1, 10),
            'created_at' => now(),
            'updated_at' => now(),
        ];
    }
```

Laravel documentation has `'user_id' => User::factory(),` I can't use this because it returns an object and I can't concatenate to string.

Below is the code for the property seeder.

```
public function run()
    {
        Property::factory()
            ->has(Category::factory()->count(3))
            ->has(PropertyImage::factory()->count(3), 'images')
            ->count(5)
            ->create();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> Laravel documentation has 'user_id' => User::factory(), I can't use this because it returns an object and I can't concatenate to string.

Yup, that will return a `UserFactory` object just as `Property::factory()` will return a `PropertyFactory`. What you want to do is call the `create()` method on the factory and get the `id` from the record that is created.

```
$proprty_id = (\App\Models\Property::factory()->create())->id;
```

Comment: There is  problem. When I use this the number of properties created is wrong. I am creating only 5 records. But when using this it creates 20 records

Comment: @Akhilesh How are you using the above code, is it in a loop? Please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73985665/edit) to include your updated code.

Comment: Updated. No, in the seeder I am using has() method.

Comment: No. I am just running `php artisan db:seed`

Comment: If I comment this line, then it is working correctly

Comment: @Akhilesh You're creating 5 `Property` models using `count(5)` but then inside your `PropertyImage` factory, you're creating another `Property`...

Answer (score 0):

Laravel extracts the ID from the `SomeModel::factory()`, that's all the magic of Laravel. To do this, you need to properly describe the `SomeModelFatory`. You can use: `$property_id = Property::factory();`

As far as I know `faker->image` no longer works, I can advise using an auxiliary class for image formation.

```
<?php

namespace App\Helpers;

use Faker\Factory;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class Image
{
    public static function imageUrl(
        int $width = 640,
        int $height = 480,
        bool $randomizeColors = false,
        bool $randomizeTxt = false,
        string $format = 'jpg'
    ): string
    {
        $baseUrl = "https://dummyimage.com";
        $size = "/{$width}x{$height}";
        $colors = "/aaa/fff";
        $format = '.' . preg_replace('~^\b(?:jpg|png|gif)$~', 'jpg', $format);

        if ($randomizeColors) {
            $backgroundColor = str_replace('#', '', Factory::create()->safeHexColor);
            $foreColor = str_replace('#', '', Factory::create()->safeHexColor);
            $colors = "/{$backgroundColor}/{$foreColor}";
        }

        return $baseUrl . $size . $colors . $format . ($randomizeTxt ? '&text=' . Factory::create()->word : '');
    }

    public static function fake(
        string $dir = null,
        int $width = 640,
        int $height = 480,
        bool $randomizeColors = false,
        bool $randomizeTxt = false,
        string $format = 'jpg',
        bool $fullPath = false
)
    {
        $dir = is_null($dir) ? sys_get_temp_dir() : $dir;

        if (!is_dir($dir) || !is_writable($dir)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Unable to write to directory $dir");
        }

        $name = md5(uniqid(empty($_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR']) ? '' : $_SERVER['SERVER_ADDR'], true));
        $filename = $name . ".$format";
        $filepath = $dir . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $filename;

        $url = static::imageUrl($width, $height, $randomizeColors, $randomizeTxt, $format);

        try {
            $image = file_get_contents($url, false, stream_context_create(['http' => ['timeout' => 10]]));

            try {
                if (!File::put($filepath, $image)) {
                    return false;
                }
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
        }

        return $fullPath ? $filepath : $filename;
    }
}
```

and use:

```
public function definition()
{
    $property_id = Property::factory();
    $dir = storage_path('app' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'public' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $property_id);
    mkdir($dir, 755);

    return [
        'name' => (\App\Helpers\Image())->fake($dir, 200, 200),
        'sort_order' => $this->faker->numberBetween(1, 10)
        ];
    }
```

Comment: Getting error `Call to undefined function App\Helpers\Image()`

Comment: @Akhilesh you need using class ```App\Helpers\Image``` from this answer. Point out in use block ```use App\Helpers\Image``` in your ```SomeModelFactory``` class. In this case, class ```App\Helpers\Image``` must be located in the directory ```app\Helpers``` so ```app\Helpers\Image.php``` (PSR-4).